How to get an array of displays in C# for a Windows CE 5.0 application with .NET CF2.0
I'm trying to develop a Windows CE application in C# in .NET CF2.0 and wanted to know how to get an array of screens. Normally this is done with Screen.AllScreens, but in CF2.0 that is not available. How could I translate Screen.AllScreens to get an array of screens in CF2.0?
In fact, I need the Working Area rectangles, not the Bounds rectangles. I've tried EnumDisplayDevices/EnumDisplaySettings, but as far as I could find, that leads to the resolution and not to the Working Area.
Thanks.
